# Constants of Integration, lhs or rhs?

Tags: calculus, integration, dynamical-systems

I'm working through Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos (Strogatz) whilst watching the MAE lectures from Prof. Strogatz.

In the example of $\dot{x}=Sin(x)$, the book integrates it as $$t=-ln|Csc(x)+Cot(x)|+C$$
where as in the lecture the professor integrates it as $$-ln|Csc(x)+Cot(x)|=t+C$$
In the book, solving for $C$ at $x=x_0$ at $t=0,C=ln|Csc(x_0)+Cot(x_0)|$, which makes sense. But in the lectures, it was also solve as $C=ln|Csc(x_0)+Cot(x_0)|$, whilst it should have been $-ln|Csc(x)+Cot(x)|$.

Same thing happens at example 2.5.1 in the book. $$\int{}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}dx=\int{dt}$$
$$\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{2}{3}}=t+C$$

Where is the constant term $C$ supposed to go?

Comment: When integrating, add $D$ to the left hand side and $E$ to the right hand side. Then work with your initial conditions and finally, you'll end up with an equation $f(t)+D=g(t)+E$ which you can write $f(t)=g(t)+E-D$ or $f(t)+D-E=g(t)$. Since $D$ and $E$ are arbitrary constants you may choose $D-E=C$ or $E-D=C$.

Comment: You can put the constant on either side, since a positive constant on the left is equivalent to a negative constant on the right, and vice versa.  In other words, if you solve a problem and put $C$ on the left, and I solve the same problem and put $C$ on the right, then my value for my $C$ will be the negative of your value for your $C$. So we're using the letter $C$ to mean different thinngs, but each of us should end up with the same result in the end.  Just make sure that, whichever side you choose, you keep the same choice throughout that calculation.